# Gumming up the works with ThreadPool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, signalr, threadpool

I am having issues trying to get the status of how many things are left to process using SignalR. I have a starting number and every time an item completes I have it increment a counter. However, the user isn't being notified in the manner the code would suggest.

---

I'm not entirely sure how to word this, but here goes. I'm queuing up a series of passengers to process and then processing them. If my understanding is correct, the processing starts immediately after the first thread is queued. After everyone is queued, every second there is a SignalR call to inform the user of where we are in the process. However, the SignalR call isn't working as expected.

Next, code:

```
            StatusInfo.SendStatus("Retrieving Passenger Details");
            foreach (var passenger in manifestResponse.Manifest.PassengerList)
            {
                //Spin up all the threads.
                PassengerThreads++;
                TotalPassengers++;
                //StatusInfo.SendStatus(TotalPassengers - PassengerThreads, 0, TotalPassengers, StartTime);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(GetSinglePassengerDetails), passenger);
                if (TotalPassengers % 5 == 0)
                {
                    StatusInfo.SendStatus(TotalPassengers - PassengerThreads, 0, TotalPassengers, StartTime);
                }
            }                
            //Wait for them to be done.
            do
            {
                StatusInfo.SendStatus(TotalPassengers - PassengerThreads, 0, TotalPassengers, StartTime);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            while (PassengerThreads > 0);
```

So what it happening is that I will send the threads to the pool to run, however, during the send status loop it does not actually send anything back. When I open the console in the browser there's a 20 second gap between showing "Retrieving Passenger Details" and the first X of Y status. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Maybe using the wrong threading model? Thanks.

Comment: From your question it is not clear how you use SignalR or even which calls are using SignalR. I also don't understand why you want to start threads - SignalR is asynchronous and you can start many concurrent tasks without having to deal with threads.

Comment: You can take a look on my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37674412/5703316

Comment: The "SendStatus" call is the SignalR call. It's a different class because the class that is calling it already inherits something. The starting of threads is so we can process every related item based on the available cores which shaves about twenty seconds off the process.

Put another way, spin up at max 240 threads, start processing them and every second report how many have been completed. However, it doesn't quite work as it says 0 of 240 for a while and then jumps to like 180 of 240. It makes no sense.